# C-shell : foreach ls cannot detect file name with dash/hyphen (-)

Tags: foreach, ls, csh

I have a c shell script that filter for a file with condition as below:

```
*_[+-]*[A-D]*.txt
```

Example of file:

Reflow_-12_A124er.txt

My script as below:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

cd /data
foreach file (`ls *_[+-]*[A-D]*.txt`)
echo "file: " $file
gzip $file
end
```

If i try command `ls *_[+-]*[A-D]*.txt` in data folder, there is output for the txt file.
But if i try run the script, the script not detect the file with (-) even tough it meets the filter.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't understand why, but this works:

```
foreach file (`ls *_[+--]*[A-D]*.txt`)
```

And so does this:

```
foreach file (`ls *_[--+]*[A-D]*.txt`)
```

You would think I'm accidentally including the `,` character that rests between `+` and `-` on the ASCII table, right? Nope. The script didn't pick up my example file, `Reflow_,77D123ab.txt`.

The documentation for csh clearly states that putting the dash at the beginning of the character class will represent a literal dash (and also that some versions of csh accept the dash at the end), but maybe it's a bug to do with `+` being a quantifier, or it just needs more than 2 characters in the character class to work properly.